# Can you embed a lighting component on a section in an existing page layout like visual force

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a requirement where I need to embed a lightning component on the details tab of a lightning record page in a page layout section. I know this is possible in visual force but can we embed a lightning component on the details tab? Can you guys share any link on how to do it?
Buyan

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to go to the details page of a record and click the gear icon where you usually go to setup. After clicking the gear icon, there should be an 'Edit Page' option. Click on that and it should open the detail page in Lightning App Builder for that specific object's detail page.